# How to use myString.PadLeft?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Why doesn't this work ?

```
string myString = "test";
int i = myString.Length; // i = 4
myString.PadLeft(5, '_'); // "myString" is should be equal to "_test", but it still "test"
i = myString.Length; // i = 4 (should be 5)
```

Comment: It's a forgivable mistake and one that you'll never make again ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most string methods don't change string itself, but return new string, so use it like this:

```
myString = myString.PadLeft(5, '_');
```

EDIT: Ahh yes, all methods. I thought about methods that don't return string and somehow ended with not entirely true sentence.

Comment: Make that _all_ string methods.

Comment: Read "most" as "all". Strings are immutable in .Net

Comment: Exactly. `System.String` is immutable, so you always have topick up the return value of the method call and assign.